# query against a variable containing a table in pl sql

Tags: plsql

I know it's maybe a silly question, however I would appreciate the best practice for it:

What I want to do in pseudo-code:

> variable1 varchar2(64);
>   variable2 varchar2(64);
>
> Select attribute1 INTO variable1 FROM controll_tabel

variable1 now contains a string, which is an existing table I want to query.

> Select max(attribute2) into variable2 from variable1

This doesn't work :-/ I also tried several dynamicSQL statements, however none of them worked for me.

Is there a way to get this done this way or is there a common best practice for this ?

Thanks for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the solution. Could you show us some of your "several dynamicSQL statements"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and might be written as:

```
execute immediate '
    select max(attribute2)
    from '||sys.dbms_assert.enquote_name(variable1)||'
' into variable2;
```